# Catching error stacktraces when DEBUG = False

Tags: django

I catch an error whenever I turn my project to `DEBUG = False`, and since no exceptions are printed, all I get is a `You need to create a 500.html template.` error message. How can I see the stacktrace of the original error in the `manage.py runserver` output?

Alternatively, can I create a 500  template which prints out the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Cat Plus Plus, I needed to set up my SMTP connection to get email notifications of the errors. They included the stacktraces I needed to hear.

Comment: Might want to look into [Django Sentry](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sentry). From the docs: "Sentry provides you with a generic interface to view and interact with your error logs. By default, it will catch any exception thrown by Django and store it in a database. With this it allows you to interact and view near real-time information to discover issues and more easily trace them in your application." Basically, it's what you put on your production server so you don't have to depend on email.

Answer (score 1):

To see the output of the runserver -commands stack trace its just a matter of looking at the terminal its running in.

For the 500 page, What would the use case of this be? 
runserver shouldn't be used outside of DEBUG=True and any real web server would log the error in a file. but to answer your question, i dont think it can be done, and shouldn't be done as your stacktraces can contain sensitive information.

Comment: How can I find out what's going wrong then? The only output I'm seeing is the 500 not found error, no other error is shown.

Comment: @TKKocheran: Configure the SMTP connection, and you'll get mail notifications with tracebacks. The error page is supposed to not say anything.